# Applying jQuery styiling inside the render() method of a Backbonejs view

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a simple hierarchy of objects (backbone), for example:

```
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({ //child class
    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template( $("#personTemplate").html() ), // RETURNS A FUNCTION!!!

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    }
});

var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({    //container class
    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function(){

        this.collection.each( function( person ){
            var personVar = new PersonView( {model : person} );
            this.$el.append( personVar.render().el );
            }, this);

            return this;
    }
});
```

This is just an example. Let's say I want to apply a red color for each `<li>` element (this represents a person) with jQuery. This method (example: `$('li').css('color', 'red')`) has to be called somewhere inside the ***PersonView*** so when I get to instantiate it inside the PeopleView, the element already has that style applied (***via jQuery***).

Again, I am interested to know if this is possible through jQuery (especially with a method called inside the child class - PersonView), not through CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone views always have a reference to their associated DOM elements, [`View.el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) :

> All views have a DOM element at all times (the *el* property), whether they've already been inserted into the page or not. In this fashion, views can be rendered at any time[...]

By extension, `View.$el` always points to the correct jQuery element, thus you can apply any jQuery function in your PersonView render:

```
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template( $("#personTemplate").html() ),

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        this.$el.css('color', 'red');
        return this;
    }
});
```

See this Fiddle for a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/64QWX/